# Problem: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode

Tags: hibernate

Here is My Query

```
public List<LocationReviewListDto> findByLocation(Long locationId, Integer page) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("select com.filmthere.dto.LocationReviewListDto(l.id, l.user,l.review, l.rating, l.createdAt)"
                + " from LocationReview l where l.location.id =:locationId", LocationReviewListDto.class).setParameter("locationId", locationId)
                .setFirstResult(page)
                .setMaxResults(20)
                .getResultList();
```

I am Getting this Error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
```

Please Help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation worked for me

give initial mapping which will map to DTO

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "DatasetMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = NativeTest.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "datasetKey")} // here it will map with result value of query
    )
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "apiKeys")
public class ApiKey {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "apikey")
    private String apiKey;

}
```

specify your `DTO` class

// NativeTest

```
public class NativeTest {

    private String datasetKey;

    public NativeTest(String datasetKey) {
        this.datasetKey = datasetKey;
    }

    public String getDatasetKey() {
        return datasetKey;
    }

    public void setDatasetKey(String datasetKey) {
        this.datasetKey = datasetKey;
    }
}
```

Now, use native query with `name` value as specified in `SqlResultSetMapping`

```
List<NativeTest> result = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT apiKey as datasetKey FROM db.apiKeys AD WHERE AD.accountId = ?", "DatasetMapping").setParameter(1, "my account id").getResultList();
```